# Unlimited downvoting questions on Area51

Tags: bug, voting, area-51

Every user can cast **5 upvotes** on example questions of a proposal. If a proposal has 40 questions with at least 10 upvotes it goes into commitment.

But I just noticed I can downvote **as many questions as I like**. So one person that disagrees with a proposal can overweigh the ones that agree by factor 10 (depending on the number of example questions).

That can't be right?!

Comment: I won't ask how you figured this out. ;) My guess would be that it's intended: A proposal should be strong enough to make it through one or two nay-sayers. Obviously it's worked so far. . .

Comment: How I figured it out? After every so precious upvote you cast you get a message how many upvotes you have left. Downvote 10 questions and you get no messages.

Comment: Hmm. Not exactly conclusive, but convincing. I stand by my "strong proposal" theory even so. Is trolling of proposals so common on Area 51 as to make this possibility a concern? (I don't participate there, so I'm just asking.)

Comment: I can't say. I have only 1 strong proposal there. I get some downvotes every few days. But probably not more than 5 downvotes every time.

Comment: @JonathanGarber: But your *strong proposals can stand that* - argument does not hold for me. That is like saying serial voting is acceptable on high-rep users - they have enough rep to ignore that.

Comment: You're right, and I should have been clearer that that's my theory as to why it's the status quo, not that "I think it should be this way". This is clearly broken, and only the relative calmness of Area 51 keeps that brokeness from being problematic. That being said, I have a feeling the developers are going to leave this one as "status-ignored" for the reasons stated in my first comment.

Comment: It's not a bug but by-design. I'd like to make it feature-request, but first, we should think what it should like?

Comment: IMO if you have 5 upvotes on a proposal you should get the same amount of downvotes or make it 5 votes, no matter if up or down.